# NSUserDefaults - saving scrollView offset

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

Here is my code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"scrolled!");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:self.mainTableView.contentOffset.y forKey:@"grTableCOy"];
}
```

As you can see every time the user scroll, I'm setting some values in NSUserDefaults. Just a question - is this efficient?

Does NSUserDefaults save stuff to disk every time I set a new value or it save it only when synchronize method is called?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this efficient?

Do you really mean efficient? Or rather "effective"? I think so. Let's see:

> Does NSUserDefaults save stuff to disk every time I set a new value or it save it only when synchronize method is called?

Neither. It saves its data periodically, so not every time when you set it, and not only when you call `- synchronize`. But, if you want to be 100% absolutely sure that your changes are saved, you can either:

- call `- synchronize` after setting a group of data every time, or
- call `- synchronize` in the methods only which get called when your application is about to move into the background or to terminate. This way your data will always be safe.

**Edit:** So you were asking about efficiency for real. Well, since `NSUserDefaults` behaves as I described, you don't have to worry, it won't perform 100 writes to disk per second, and since you stated that you're calling `synchronize` before application termination, your data is also safe.

Comment: I'm calling synchronize on applicationWillTerminate. But is this good for energy saving? I mean let's say the user scroll the table. The method didScroll is fired like 100 times. NSUserDefaults saves let's say only 10 times, but this is still writing to disk, so it is energy efficient? That was my question.

Comment: @Devfly If you synchronize in `applicationWillTerminate`, that's good. `NSUserDefaults` won't save every time you scroll one (only set the underlying `NSDictionary` in memory), so you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The [NSUserDefaults manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has some information on the caching, and this part should answer your question;

> NSUserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value. The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.

In other words, your changes are just efficiently stored *in memory* and unless you call `synchronize` manually the data won't be persisted every time you change a value but instead but at periodic intervals.

If you really want to be sure that the value is written and stored, you can call `synchronize` to manually make that happen. This is probably a good idea when the app is about to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't speak to the performance aspects of what you are doing.  The only way to get a definite answer is fire up instruments, and measure the response of the scrollview with and without using NSUserDefaults.

To the question of does it save?  Well, in this case, a trip to the documentation should answer the question.  Here's a snippet from the synchronize method:

```
Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk 
and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.
```

Again, the only way to be sure of performance issues is to measure in instruments.

Good luck!